# Pymongo is fetching the database connection but not doing any CRUD operation and throwing me bad auth error

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

#### Problem Facing

I am trying to set up CRUD using flask and pymongo to MongoDB collection. However, I am able to fetch the collections but I am not able to perform any CRUD operation on the collections. I have already created a user with all admin privileges and added the creds to my mongodb URI.

#### Code

```py
import os
import pymongo
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()

PASSWORD = os.getenv("MONGODB_PASSWORD")
DB_NAME = os.getenv("MONGODB_DB_NAME")
USERNAME=os.getenv('MONGODB_USERNAME')

client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}>@cluster0-7hkix.mongodb.net/{DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = client['cms_user']
user_info = db['UserInfo']
rate_data = db['rate_data']

print(user_info, rate_data)

send_dict = {
"Name": 'a',
"Mail": 'asda',
"age": 2,
"address": 'asdasd',
"uname": 'asdasd',
"pwd": 'a',
"cpwd": 'a'
}

try:
    user_info.insert(send_dict)
except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as e:
    print(e.code, e.details)
```

#### Ouput

The output i am getting after running this

```sh
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['cluster0-shard-00-01-7hkix.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-02-7hkix.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-00-7hkix.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='Cluster0-shard-0', ssl=True), 'cms_user'), 'UserInfo') Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['cluster0-shard-00-01-7hkix.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-02-7hkix.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-00-7hkix.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, retrywrites=True, w='majority', authsource='admin', replicaset='Cluster0-shard-0', ssl=True), 'cms_user'), 'rate_data')
8000 {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

#### Mongo DB User details

I have created User on mongodb Atlas with full read write access privileges as given here
[user access on db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0H9p.png)

#### System Configuration

- Python version - Python 3.6.8
- OS - Windows 10 Home
- pymongo - version 3.10.1 with srv support

Comment: Test connecting with the mongo shell using that same connection string to see if the problem is with the connection string or python.

Comment: Your "output" specifies `admin` as auth source, your first code segment does not. Which is it?

Comment: @D. SM No actually my mongodb user is admin only , that is why its showing the same

Comment: ok @joe i will do the following